# JSON decode from url in Go

Tags: json, go

I have my php code. How to create something like this in Go?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
     'ignore_errors'=>true,
     'method'=>'GET'
   )
));
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ of how to make a GET request and http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ of how to decode the recieved json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)

    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if dec == nil {
        panic("Failed to start decoding JSON data")
    }

    json_map := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = dec.Decode(&json_map)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", json_map)
}
```

Comment: How can I add additional parametrs to URL from array? For example: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?code=253&demo=32535`

Comment: @leliwa19 what do you mean by parameters from array? Take a look at this -- http://play.golang.org/p/zFfiMy2C0i. Note that you'll need to do your own escaping of keys and values to keep the URL valid.

Comment: Note that you need to close res.Body.